# Can't embed/link YouTube video

Tags: html, video, youtube

I am attempting to embed/link a YouTube video into my HTML file. However, after I copy and paste my embed link from YouTube into my HTML document, nothing appears to happen.

Here is the YouTube link I am using:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-            qZ8GkTWQ04" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Here is full code (an assignment for an Intro to Web class):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Intro</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1 align="center" style="color:yellow; background-    color:blue">Introduction: TextWrangler</h1>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="intro.html">Intro</a></li>
      <li><a href="pros.html">Pros</a></li>
      <li><a href="cons.html">Cons</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div align="center">
    <img   src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
</div>

<p>TextWrangler is a free to download and use text editor. It is often   considered the "little brother"
of BBEdit. TextWrangler is a leading HTML and text editor for Mac.   Apple's App Store
introduced TestWrangler as a "powerful, general-purpose text editor crafted in Bare Bones Software's best traditions. For anyone who works with text, this award-winning application provides a clean, intelligent interface to a rich set of features for editing, searching, and manipulation of text with high performance".
</p>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-qZ8GkTWQ04" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ProgrammerKid/Lzq4557r/

(the JSFiddle shows how the html code should look like)

in the src, it is supposed to be:

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-qZ8GkTWQ04"
```

you put

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-            qZ8GkTWQ04"
```

Comment: I think it just got messed up when I copy and pasted from my document to Stack Overflow